# Show in LAS file the curve Mnemonics on ~ASCII section with lasio

Tags: python-3.x, log-ascii-standard

When writing a LAS file using:

```
 las_data.write(new_File,version=2.0)
```

I loose the curve Mnemonics placed on the ~A or ~ASCII line
My petrophysicist loves seeing them listed on that line just above the data columns. When writing a LAS file using lasio it doesn't work

Below is the code showing how I create the line - same as I write when altering other headeritem lines. From reading the LASIO documentation I started to wonder whether those Mnemonics are included as column headers in the dataframe with the data columns. Hence the final statement line below but to no avail.

```
    #Update encode ~ASCII with curve names
        las_dat.encoding = "~ASCII DEPT"
        counter = 0
        for curve in las_dat.curves:
            x=6 #spaces between curve Mnem
            if counter>0:
                las_dat.encoding = las_dat.encoding + " "*(x- 
                    len(curve.mnemonic.strip(' ')))+curve.mnemonic.strip(' ')
            counter = counter + 1
        las_dat.set_data(df)         #Seems like ~A line is part of df
```

Here is an example of the ~ASCII line:
'~ASCII DEPT   ILM   SFL   ILD  CILD    SP  NPSS    C1  DRHO  RHOB  DPSS   PEF    GR  HDIA'

Comment: This is a great idea but not implemented yet. See https://github.com/kinverarity1/lasio/issues/375 for the issue which will be updated once the feature is written in.

Comment: Also see https://github.com/kinverarity1/lasio/pull/465, which adds mnemonics_header and data_section_header keyword arguments to writer.py:write.

Answer (score 0):

This is partially available in the current Lasio release: [v0.30](https://github.com/kinverarity1/lasio/releases/tag/v0.30)

- "Partially fix #375 (allow writing mnemonics in ~ASCII line; PRs #466, #471, #465)"